# Java and MongoDB threading

Tags: java, multithreading, mongodb

I have just started MongoDB + Java, and I am getting into queries, collections etc.

Since the databases I'm playing are really small, everything is on the main thread. But, in general, is it a good idea to put all mongo queries etc on another thread?

Comment: I think it depends on application you are writing, if it is kind of batch job and the queries have to be serialized in some order threads won't help you. On the other hand if you are writing GUI application (for example in Swing) long running tasks make you application freezing, so it's better to use another threads...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officially the [Java driver is thread safe](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Driver+Concurrency). So you don't need to worry much about threading. If you need high performance and aren't too worried about data accuracy (e.g. logging hits to a web page) you can even enable [`WriteConcern.NONE`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/WriteConcern.html) and the Java process will not even wait for Mongo to report a success.